# .htaccess, Rewriterule not working as i want

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this link: `http://www.domain.com.mk/lajmi.php?id=2790,`
and i want to change it to `http://www.domain.com.mk/lajmi/2790`

With this code I can change the link to /lajmi/2790 but i get 404 error. 
I mean i get the link

`http://www.domain.com.mk/lajmi/2790`, but it has 404 error (i dont se the content)

This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com\.mk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com\.mk$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^lajmi\.php$ http://domain.com.mk/lajmi/%1? [R=302,L]
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Rewriting aside, what is the **real** uri that has content? If you want the URL **look** like this: `http://www.domain.com.mk/lajmi/2790`, but actually be served by `http://www.domain.com.mk/lajmi.php?id=2790`, then you're rewriting in wrong direction...

Comment: Thats what i am looking for, this is the real url: http://www.portali.com.mk/lajmi.php?id=2799

Comment: What would be the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com\.mk$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d*)$
RewriteRule ^lajmi\.php$ http://domain.com.mk/lajmi/%1? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^lajmi/(\d*)$ lajmi.php?id=$1&r=0 [L]
```

(the &r=0 in the final rule is for not getting an infinite loop)

Comment: This dos the job but the content is not well structured, i lost the layout of the page. The content is all there but the structure is not as should be.

Comment: @AgonXheladini what happens is the browser now *thinks* it is in `lajmi/` subfolder, so all relative paths to images, css, etc are going from there. either use absolute paths or add `<base href="/">` to your html

Comment: Can you explain better this <base href = "/">, what is this base tag ?

Comment: [Quote](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4): `href = uri` - This attribute specifies an absolute URI that acts as the base URI for resolving relative URIs

Answer (score 0):

Single direction rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com\.mk$ 
RewriteRule ^lajmi/(\d*)$ lajmi.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This means that every uri of kind `/lajmi/2790` will be passed to `/lajmi.php?id=2790` in a sub-request.

However, in this case, if the user hits `/lajmi.php?id=2790` by himself, then this is the url he will see in the browser, not the "beautified one".

---

Bi-directional rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

; Redirect lajmi.php?id=2790 to a beutified version, but only if not in sub-request!
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com\.mk$
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} !=true
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d*)$
RewriteRule ^lajmi\.php$ lajmi/%1 [R=301,L]

; Make the beutified uri be actually served by lajmi.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com\.mk$
RewriteRule ^lajmi/(\d*)$ lajmi.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Here, an additional `RewriteCond` was added to the first rule checking that this is not a sub-request, to ensure that the rules do not loop.

---

You can pick which way you like, but the first approach is enough if you build the links in your HTML in the 'beautified' way already (no need to redirect the browser twice just to see the page).